# can I configure an enrichment step to an API via API Gateway using EventBridge pipes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I am working with an Event Bridge pipe and its working ok, but the enrichment step is done by a lambda and now I want to move it to ECS instances, there is one option from AWS where you can configure different types of enrichers, including API Gateway, I created one API gateway but everytime I try to pick it, I see all the list empty (attached photo).

Is this possible? if yes, why is this empty? Any idea about it?
[image]